# Foreman Procfile for dev & prod environments

Tags: foreman

Is there a way to have foreman conditionally start certain processes in the Procfile?  I would like foreman to run both a web and worker process in production but in my dev environment I only need the web process.

**Production:**

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application
worker: python worker.py
```

**Development:**

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an alternate Procfile and use that to start foreman.

```
$ cat Procfile.local
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application

$ cat Procfile
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application
worker: python worker.py

$ foreman start --procfile Procfile.local
```

if using git then add the file to the .gitignore file so that it stays local.

```
$ cat .gitignore | egrep local
.local
```